# Strange jquery ajax quirk, return object is correct, properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for hours on this problem, read a lot on fora and SO, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My return object *data* is logged out correctly, but as soon as i try to access a property, it is always undefined???? How come?

I tried to do `data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` as a suggested answer in some SO posts, but my problem remains.

All help is welcome!

BTW:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btw").on('focusout',function () {
                    console.log("BTW validation check. (REST CALL)");

                    var btw = $(this).val();
                    var country_code = btw.substring(0,2);
                    var vat_number = btw.substring(2);

                    console.log("country_code: " + country_code);
                    console.log("vat_number: " + vat_number);

                    $.getJSON('http://vatid.eu/check/'+ country_code +'/'+vat_number, function(data) { 

                        console.log(data); // good object with valid set

                        console.log(data["valid"]); //undefined!
                        console.log(data.valid); //undefined!

                        /*
                        if(data.valid) {
                            $("#order_custom_10").value = true
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#order_custom_10").value = false
                        }
                        */
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: please show us your "good" output of `console.log(data);`.

Comment: ^ this. We need to see the structure of the json coming back - your references may be nested an additional layer, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` object returned by the request has a `response` object with the data you want. So use `data.response.valid` to get what you want.

This is the JSON object structure from vatid.eu:

```
{
  "response": {
      "country_code": "DK",
      "vat_number": "30505166",
      "valid": "true",
      "name": "JUSTABOUTIT ApS",
      "address": "Gammeltorv 8 2\n1457 København K\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post source for that information please? I am finding contradictory information on jQuery docs

Comment: @mhodges sorry for delay - just saw your comment. The JSON object returned isn't structured by jQuery - it's the http://vatid.eu/check serverside code that builds the JSON response. So, check [Vat ID's docs](http://vatid.eu) for the structure specification.